# Views - How to display results in nested groups?

Tags: 7, views

I have a View listing out members of staff. Each staff member belongs to a department, or sub-department. I want to list out all staff members but group them under their (sub)-department in a nested manner. For example:

```
# School Board
John Doe

# Teaching Staff
Jane Doe

    ## Chemistry
    Eric Betzig

    ## Physics
    Shuji Nakamura
    Isamu Akasaki
```

I know you can use the Group by Fields option, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828952/drupal-7-views-list-group-by-field/13829576#13829576), but it doesn't allow for nesting:

```
# School Board
John Doe

# Teaching Staff
Jane Doe

# Chemistry // Not nested
Eric Betzig

# Physics // Not nested
Shuji Nakamura
Isamu Akasaki
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module.

The logic is as follows:

1. Create a View listing out the terms (I call it the 'Tree View')

   ```
   # School Board
   # Teaching Staff
   # Chemistry
   # Physics
   ```
2. Create a View which takes a Contextual Filter of `Content: Has taxonomy term ID` and display all content with this term ID. (I call this the 'Content View')

   ```
   ## Physics
       Shuji Nakamura
       Isamu Akasaki
   ```
3. We have the building blocks, now let's combine the two Views together. In the 'Tree View', add a relationship with the Parent term (`Taxonomy term: Parent term`) and add `(Parent) Taxonomy term: Term Name` to the fields. Now go to *Format > Settings* and Group the result by `(Parent) Taxonomy term: Term Name` and check *'Use rendered output to group rows'*

   ```
   # School Board
   # Teaching Staff
       ## Chemistry
       ## Physics
   ```
4. Still in the 'Tree View', add the `(Parent) Taxonomy term: Term ID` and `Global: View` fields. In the settings, under *View*, select your 'Content View',  and under *Contextual filters*, put `[!tid]` in order to pass the term ID to the 'Content View'. And we are good to go!

   ```
   # School Board
   John Doe

   # Teaching Staff
   Jane Doe

       ## Chemistry
       Eric Betzig

       ## Physics
       Shuji Nakamura
       Isamu Akasaki
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more a question of styling than views itself. You could assign a class to the row output (e.g. with a replacement pattern token or something) and then style the css to show the output "nested".